# How to check if something printed using random module is repeated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

This is my code so far:

```
import random

words = ['a', 'b', 'c']
def abc():
    print(random.choice(words))
    input('Press Enter to Continue')
    abc()
abc()
```

How can I make it so every time it prints a word from the list `words`, it checks if it has been repeated before? I would prefer the answer being either in python without modules or with the `random` module.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If your goal is to print things just once but in a random order, use `random.shuffle()`. If you really want, you can use a `set` to keep track of what you have printed.

Comment: It sounds as if you want to *shuffle* `words` instead, then just iterate over the randomised order. That way you won't get the same word repeated.

Comment: I suggest you write a proper loop instead of calling `abc` inside itself.

Comment: This sounds like the XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Can you re-formulate your question to describe the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @TomDalton yes sorry I didn't have any idea (or solution) on how to actually do it so I don't think it's that problem. Also many people answered the question so again, i don't think that's the problem but thanks anyways this article is useful :)

Comment: @JohnColeman The thing is that I want to press Enter to actually show the next word and Kaushik NP's answer only prints everything once. Maybe my question is faulty if you have a suggestion on something to change for future viewers to understand please tell me.

Comment: @VagosA. What is preventing you from doing that? If you only want the words printed out one at a time when Enter is pressed -- just take that solution and put `input('Press Enter to Continue')` at the bottom of the loop (right after `print(word)`)

Answer (score 1):

As @John pointed pointed out, just use `random.shuffle`.

> `random.shuffle(x[, random])`
>
> Shuffle the sequence x in place. The
>   optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a random
>   float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, this is the function random().

```
random.shuffle(words)

print(words)

#loop
for word in words:
      print(word)
```

Will give:

```
IN : words = ['a', 'b', 'c']
OUT : ['c', 'a', 'b']                         #This is random
```

**Note 1 :** advantage of using `shuffle` is that there is no risk of you getting the same element twice.

**Note 2 :** Be careful though, as using shuffle will affect your original variable in which the data is stored too. In case you want to retain the original sequence, I would suggest you copy the data in another variable and use that in `shuffle`.